# Wild card search in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have searched the interweb and have not found something that works. Here is what I am trying to do

I want the user to be able to do a wildcard search using an Asterisk such as `(M*chael)` to return Michael. But I also want it to do a full LIKE (example `M*ichael` searches `%M*chael%`).

I have not been able to find anything that works, I have tried

```
.Where(m => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(newFilter, m.Manufacturer.strLocation.ToUpper()) > 0);
```

and I tried this as well

[Wildcard Search Helper Entity Framework](https://gist.github.com/MoienTajik/40b29c6fa65baa2dd44127d588bda395)

No luck and very frustrated. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Which EF version are you using? In any case there's no reason to use `ToUpper` as databases commonly use case-*in*sensitive collations

Comment: `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` returns the index of the first match, so you need to compare that against 0 to see if a match was found, eg `.Where(m=>SqlFunctions.PatIndex(newFilter,m.Manufacturer)>0)`

Comment: As for an *asterisk*, you can't use it. In SQL, the language, the wildcard character is `%`, not `*`. To match a single character use `_`, not `.`. The equivalent pattern for `M*chael` is `M_chael` if you only want a single character, `M%chael` if you want to match multiple

Comment: Create a Stored Procedure with the search variables as needed and return the corresponding objects. Search on How to call a stored procedure from Entity Framework on how to do it.